# mount <pendrive>/home as /home/ubuntu in live USB ubuntu

Tags: live-usb

I have created a customised version of Ubuntu (basically I just installed the programs that I want), using UCK, to install on a pendrive and carry with me while travelling and boot on whatever computer is available.

What I want is to have a "home" folder on the pendrive and then mount it as /home/ubuntu in the live system.
That way, I can easily access my files from other systems as well as the pendrive, and the settings for the screen, etc will be reset every time I boot and won't cause problems when I use it on multiple machines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest method is to use persistence. Make a file called `home-rw`

```
# this will make a 1 Gb file for storage, increase / decrease the count as needed
dd if=/dev/zero of=./home-rw bs=1M count=1000
```

Make a file system on the file

```
mkfs.ext4 home-rw

mke2fs 1.41.14 (22-Dec-2010)
home-rw is not a block special device.

# Answer ‘yes’ here

Proceed anyway? (y,n) y
```

Remove the reserved blocks

```
tune2fs -m 0 -L home-rw home-rw
```

When you boot your pendrive , hit the tab key to edit your boot options, and add `persistent` to the boot options.

You can edit /isolinux/txt.cfg (I think that is the file) to add a persistent option, looks like this:

[image: boot splash]

Comment: I there an easy way to access the files in home-rw from my main (Ubuntu) system?

Comment: yes. `sudo mount -o loop /media/usb_name/home-rw /mnt`. Adjust the path as needed to use an alternate mount location.

Answer (score 1):

You can also create persistent partitions instead of persistent files.
Persistent partitions are not limited to the 4GB size that FAT32 files are.

Format the first partition FAT32, this is where Ubuntu Live will be installed. Format the next partitions ext2, (or ext3 or ext4), label the second partition casper-rw and the third one home-rw, (optional).

Delete the casper-rw file created by the Startup disk app.